# iOS Swift Decodable: Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, decodable

I'm getting error in initialising a struct, please see the screenshot attached below. After debugging I found that including review variable in the struct is giving problem.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Can anyone help me out?

Tx

I'm copying code just in case you need to try it out

```
import UIKit

struct RootValue : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case success = "success"
        case content = "data"
        case errors = "errors"
    }
    let success: Bool
    let content : [ProfileValue]
    let errors: [String]
}

struct ProfileValue : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case review = "review" // including this gives error
    }

    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var review: ReviewValues // including this gives error
}

struct ReviewValues : Decodable{
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case place = "place"
    }

    var place: String = ""
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var profileValue = ProfileValue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tossed your code into a Playground and was required to use `var profileValue = ProfileValue(id: 0, name: "", review: ReviewValues(place: ""))`. To overcome it, you'd have to provide a custom `init` function, but `review` is not optional, so you'd have to supply a value for it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Review has no default value , You need to change this

```
var profileValue = ProfileValue()
```

to

```
var profileValue:ProfileValue?
```

**OR**

```
var review: ReviewValues?
```

**OR**

supply `init` method in `ProfileValue` struct

Comment: Thanks I tried this var review: ReviewValues? and it's working.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ProfileValue` struct doesn’t have a default value for the `review` property. That is why the compiler is unhappy, as you’re trying to create an instance of ProfileValue without providing default values for all of the non optional properties.

As a side note, all your coding key enum values just match the property names. You don’t need to include the coding keys enum if the names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add an init to your ProfileValue struct:

```
struct ProfileValue : Decodable {
  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case review = "review" // including this gives error
  }

  var id: Int = 0
  var name: String = ""
  var review: ReviewValues // including this gives error

  init() {
    self.review = ReviewValues()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add default init method to provide the default init method in codable modal to create the encoded object.

```
struct Modal: Codable {

    var status: String?
    var result : [Result?]?

    // To provide the default init method to create the encoded object

    init?() {
        return nil
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status"
        case result = "result"
    }
}
```